# Referring to an NSString in output of UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I have an `NSString`, testString which is set to a value in my app. Then as a response to a button press in `UIAlertView` I have the following code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"String: %@", testString);
    }
}
```

But for sme reason, this always causes the app to crash. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: How are you defining and setting testString? Show more of the code you are using, because there is nothing wrong with what you have provided so far, other than not knowing how testString is created and its value is.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using an NSString in an AlertView. Like @WriteCS said, it must have something to do with your string. You say that it's "set to a value in my app," but that doesn't tell us anything meaningful. More code, more code.

Comment: you need to allocate testString & make it global (defined in header)

Comment: @tlikyu Making `testString` global is a **terrible** solution. It's needed in this AlertView delegate, we know that, but why would you think it's needed everywhere in the app, constantly taking up memory and easily conflicting with other namespaces? Maybe you don't mean "global," but instead mean that it needs to be available throughout the object, which makes more sense. "Global" has a very specific meaning, however, and it isn't that.

Comment: @matthew what i meant is to declare in header file. then can release in dealloc mehtod. sorry for misunderstanding. noted that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you create your string with one of convenience methods and don't retain it, so when it comes to alert's clickedButtonAtIndex it's already autoreleased. 
You should define it as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *testString;
```

In implementation:

```
@synthesize testString;
```

On creating:

```
self.testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"My test string"];
```

and `[testString release];` on dealloc.

Then when you use it in clickedButtonAtIndex you can be sure your testString has a right value

Comment: This works, but now i have the problem where I have another NSString is changed inside of the response to UIalertView code, and when i try and use that NSString again somewhere else, the app crashes.

Comment: the problem is probably the same. Just apply this solution. You have to retain it before using it everywhere

Comment: I applied the same solution, but it's still crashing. I'm unsure how to refer to it though. Inside the response to UIAlertView code, would i refer to it as 'self.testString2' or 'testString2' or something else? In any case, neither of these seem to work. And then back in the rest of the code, do i always have to refer to it as self.testString2 (or something else), or just the first time, which I did with the first testString?

Comment: you use dot notation, that is self.yourString = someString only in case you defined your property with retain attribute in order to invoke default setter which will retain it for you. Please bring some code for us to be helpful. It's kind of difficult to understand what you're doing w/o seeing a line of code