# Setting the value of an NSString inside a UIAlertView response, can't be used elsewhere?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I originally asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841399/referring-to-an-nsstring-in-output-of-uialertview) about getting a string value into a UIAlertView but now I need to get it out. So i've put this as a new question to tidy everything up and make it cleaner and clearer.

So here's the code I have:

In the .h file..

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myTestString;`

Then in the .m file it's synthesized with:

`@synthesize myTestString`

Then in the .m file...

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    self.myTestString = @"test";
    }
}

-(void)somethingElse {

    NSLog(@"%@", myTestString);
}
```

Then i'd release it in dealloc.

This code would cause a crash at the point of the NSLog.

How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about your use of `@synchronize` here. Properties are usually *synthesized* in the .m file, using `@synthesize propertyName;`. `@synchronize` is used for thread safety in a multi-threaded application.

The other thing I can see here is that `myTestString` can be undefined in your `-somethingElse` method because you only assign a value to the property when `buttonIndex == 0`. You may want to insert a default value for `myTestString`, either in your `-init` method, or in the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method.

To summarize, I would expect your class to look something like this:

> **MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass {
    NSString *myTestString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myTestString;
@end
```

> **MyClass.m**

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myTestString;

-(id)init {
    if ((self = [super init]) == nil) { return nil; }
    myTestString = @"";
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [myTestString release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.myTestString = @"test";
    }
}

-(void)somethingElse {
    NSLog(@"%@", myTestString);
}

@end
```

Comment: Hmm, this works in a test project i set up, but isn't working in my actual project, even though everything remains the same as above. Oh, and i did mean synthesize, not synchronize.

Comment: Does the crash log give any hints? If you run with the debugger enabled in Xcode, you can see the stack trace at the point of failure

Comment: i just had self.myTestString on the first mention of it in clickedButtonAtIndex, which seemed to be the problem. It's fixed now, thanks for your help.